# in Setting bundle, Perform action on switch toggle type to hide or change field type of another field in setting bundle ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, settings.bundle

In default setting app for Wifi, when we switch on the wifi, another section appears. Can we do such a thing? I want a switch toggle button, and on action want to add proxy fields or change the type of fields from read only to textfield.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can only do it "inside" the app, with [Settings](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Preferences/Preferences.html) app you are limited to static options layout.

Comment: Thanks for clearing my doubts. I asked this specific question because the similar apps behavior was seen in Apple's App.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3928064/3411787) is possible way.

Comment: Yes, this is a nice way to make a dynamic UI inside of your application. There's still no solution for a dynamic Settings screen though, as far as I know.