# Location Services enabled from native Settings App

Tags: ios, objective-c, location, settings

When my app is launched it requests to use location services.

If a user selects 'Don't Allow' I prompt again letting them know that Location Services are required for the best experience and they can enable in the settings app.

If a user does not allow and still creates an account, the main screen will not fully function without the location feature part.

From this point, if I manually enable in the Settings app I'm still not getting the main page to pick up the current location.

How do I detect that location services have been enabled from the Settings App?

Is there a method I need to enforce again from the AppDelegate?

Answer (score 0):

You can tell if location has been enabled for your app using CLLocationManager.AuthorizationStatus, which returns a member of the CLAuthorizationStatus enum. If location is disabled completely, your app won't be authorized, so you know everything you need to know.

```
let authorization = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()
if authorization == .AuthorizedWhenInUse || authorization == .Authorized {
    ...
}
```

If you request authorization using CLLocationManager and the user denies it, you can't cause the window to come up again.

From a UX point of view, be careful about nags as well. Communicate clearly that your app benefits from using location, but try to avoid browbeating the user about it.

Answer (score 0):

See also [how to determine when settings change on ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927402/) to have your app retry location access right after a user (hopefully) enabled it.