# Get deviceToken when user enable push notification manually when app is running in background

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

Is there a way to get Push notification token when user enabled it manually from settings while the application was in the background. 
Is there a function available in Swift which will get push notification token when user will come back to the app.

Comment: You can register for push notifications and receive a token without asking the user. The authorization request is to display the notifications, not to receive them.

Comment: Don't understand so I can have token without asking for user permissions. Any sample code how this would work

Answer (score 1):

When user turing push notification allowed in the general setting of ios, 
the app can call the

```
UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
```

and device token is able to be obtained from

```
public func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data)
```

as I understand there is no any direct method to determine the user setting push notification manually, so I came up two alternative ways

1. using NSNotification center observer to determine any setting changes as explained already [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47442448/7051103)
2. or in the Appdelegate applicationWillEnterForeground

to call bellow function (for example)

```
    func registerRemoteNotification() {
     let notificationCenter = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
     notificationCenter.getNotificationSettings { (settings) in
        if settings.authorizationStatus == .authorized {
            //"authorized"
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
              UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
             }
        } else {
          //"not authorized")
        }
      } 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use observer for system wise settings change. See more info on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927402/how-to-determine-when-settings-change-on-ios)

Comment: So how this will be called and token set?


public func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                     didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
       
        UserDefaults.standard.set(deviceToken, forKey: "deviceToken")
    }