# How to observe the event when the specific application settings value has been changed in swift 5?

Tags: xcode10, swift5, ios-settings-bundle

My application has a multi value settings bundle option. I'd like to catch the event, when this setting has been changed.

I found these possibilities, but I don't know what is the difference between them:

```
UserDefaults.standard.addObserver(observer: NSObject, forKeyPath: String, options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?)

NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(observer: NSObject, forKeyPath: String, options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to determine when Settings change on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927402/how-to-determine-when-settings-change-on-ios)

Comment: I have specified more the question - it's not a duplicate.

Comment: The ones you have added to your question are older versions from the Objective-C era defined in `NSObject`, better to use the one in the duplicate link